# Two complementary answers

Tags: discussion

Is there a recommended practice when two answers complement each other? For example, in [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/28590/6497) about iGoogle [one answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/28651/6497) suggests how to export the data while [another answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/28677/6497) suggests several options for importing the data and using it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If they are helpful to you, up-vote both. Accept the one that helped you the best. If you want, you can assign a bounty to the next answer to show that it is more than helpful to you as well.